# How to push tags with release notes to another github server?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to migrate a GIT repository from one github server to another,

I executed below commands,

```
$git clone --mirror git@github.x.com:org/repo
$git push git@github.y.com:org/repo master
$git push git@github.y.com:org/repo --tags
```

After push, I could see the commits & tags are up to date in github.y.com server, but release notes associated to tags are missing. Is there a way to update release notes associated to tags?

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way seems to be [forking a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/).

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion @Nick Volynkin, I am trying to migrate code between different github servers here. I assume fork will only help within repository.

Comment: What do you mean by github servers? Do you mean git servers or github repositories? For repositories it's possible to fork one, thus creating another.

Comment: Yes I agree fork works within repository, but I want to migrate a repository between two different github servers. Say for ex. If some company wants to move the repository from internal github server (github.xyz.com) to global github server (github.com) in order to make it open source.

Comment: Do I understand it right that 'release notes' were added with `git tag -m'release note text' tagname` ?

Comment: No, Added using github UI for e.g. go to github.xyz.com/org/repo/tags., on each tag entry you can see "Add release notes" link.

Comment: Are the release notes present on your local repo after `git clone --mirror...`? If so, maybe try `git push --mirror...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78079/discussion-between-nick-volynkin-and-jayachandran).